# Understanding Gluon Ignite Lambda Idiom

Tags: java, lambda, dagger, gluon, gluon-desktop

I set up a JavaFX Gluon Project using the Eclipse Gluon plugin and tried to get Gluon Ignite ([Gluon Ignite](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/ignite/); basically a wrapper framework to be able to use CDI in JavaFX) with Dagger going.

In an  [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/01/dependency-injection-javafx-gluon-ignite-dagger.html) I found the following Java 8 Lambda expression to create a DaggerContext object:

```
private final DaggerContext context = new DaggerContext(this, () -> Arrays.asList(new DaggerModule()));
```

This confuses me a bit as I'm quite new to Lambda expressions. Though, if it had worked flawlessly I probably wouldn't ask this question - but it doesn't ;) Eclipse reports '

> The constructor DaggerContext(GluonApplication, () -> {}) is undefined

So could someone tell me step by step what's going on there? Maybe the conservative version of code would help to understand it a bit better.

I know lambda expressions like this are used as a short form to create objects of anonymous classes. 
So when looking at the constructor of DaggerContext I see that the expression `() -> Arrays.asList(new DaggerModule())` should create an object with type `Supplier<Collection<Object>>`, but this obviously doesn't work.

--- UPDATE ---

The problem was just a simple import problem. I had to add `import java.util.Arrays;` to resolve the error. Sill, It would be nice, if someone could provide some further explanation of the lambda expression.

Comment: Since Java 8 is not yet supported for Gluon Mobile applications, I wouldn't use Ignite, which is built on it.

Comment: Well, although this has nothing to do with my question. Could you provide some proof for that? Nevertheless, I'm not really dependent on mobile...